# How to use jquery with TypeScript by using SystemJS as module loader (ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at Object.execute)

Tags: jquery, typescript, systemjs

I've yet installed jquery properly with the commands:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

and

```
npm i --save @types/jquery
```

and

```
npm install -g typings
```

and

```
typings install dt~jquery --global –save
```

I have deleted the folder typings from the file system explorer ('cause Visual Studio Code can't delete it for some reason) and I have deleted the file typings.json
I've executed also the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

The commands have been executed in the terminal of Microsoft Visual Studio Code.

I'm using SystemJS to load the modules.

File app.ts:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

(function($) {
    // Use $() inside of this function
    $("#app").css({"background-color": "green"});
})(jQuery);
```

File app.js:

```
System.register([], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            (function ($) {
                // Use $() inside of this function
                $("#app").css({ "background-color": "green" });
            })(jQuery);
        }
    };
});
```

File index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Learning TypeScript</title>
        <script src='node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">Change it with jQuery</div>

        <script>
            System.import('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
            System.import('./app.js');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

No error occurs when I execute the tsc command.

Sometimes jQuery works fine, but sometimes the following error appears in the console of the Web browser Google Chrome 77.0 when I press the F5 key (reload page):

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.execute (app.js:10)
```

Please help me to execute the jQuery code correctly.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is app.js code?? In example. It seems you have app.ts but not app.js

Comment: Hi vipul patel, I've added the app.js source code. Thanks.

Comment: you are loading jquery later then loading app.js  JS does sequential execution of the code. First load  System.import('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') and then  System.import('./app.js');

Comment: Thanks vipul patel, I've changed the source code of the HTML file but it doesn't work because of some compilation errors (listed above).

Comment: Sometimes, if I press the F5 key (reload page) jQuery works.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript needs to know where your importing `jQuery` from. `$` is apparently declared correctly, but `jQuery` may not have been.

You'll most likely need to include an import statement as follows to declare `jQuery`:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
```

Additionally, if you're having scope issues, you may want to try declaring the jquery objects globally after the above import statement as follows:

```
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

Lastly, if you want to ensure that app.ts uses any jQuery definitions that may already be globally defined, only update the globals if they don't already exist as follows:

```
window.$ = window.$ || $; 
window.jQuery = window.jQuery || jQuery;
```

Comment: Hi A-Diddy, Thanks.
I've added the following instruction to the app.ts file but an error occurs:
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
The error is: "Module '"../../../PROJECTS/typescript/typescript/node_modules/@types/jquery/index"' has no exported member 'jQuery'.ts(2305)"

Comment: Try this... 
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

Comment: Thanks. I've tried. Now the following error appears:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to resolve specifier 'jquery' from http://localhost:3000/app.js

Comment: Sounds like you got passed the transpile/build, right? Did you include the two lines to declare `$` and `jQuery` globally?

Comment: Now the compilation errors are gone away. But sometimes the error listed above appears in the console of the Web browser when I reload the page. Sometimes, if I press the F5 key (reload page) jQuery works fine.

Comment: It sounds like a timing issue. I'd have to see the code to be able to troubleshoot further. This is just a guess, but it's possible that jQuery is being defined in multiple places and the one that gets called may not be the one you want. Make sure you only define it once. For example, wherever jQuery is defined, try this... `window.jQuery = window.jQuery || jQuery`... this will only update the global definition if it's not already defined.